# ArduinoJson is not adding string to JsonObject. ArduinoJson broken?

Tags: esp32, json

So I've got this code

```
String GetTimeString(){        
    strftime(dateArray, 100, dateFormat, getTimeInfo());
    dateString = String(dateArray);
    Serial.println(dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

Being called later like this:

```
document["Time"] = GetTimeString();
```

But the resulting object looks like this:

> September 12 2020 09:49:04
> {"DryBulbTemp":80.762,"WetBulbTemp":72.74606,"Pressure":398.9942,"Humidity":68.32129,"Time":null}

So it behaves this way no matter if I print what comes out of the function immediately before the assignment to the "Time" property.  Is ArduinoJson just broken?

Comment: https://arduinojson.org/v6/faq/why-is-the-output-incomplete/

Answer (score 0):

ArduinoJson 6 works with fixed memory allocation.

When you create a [`JsonDocument`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/), you must specify its memory capacity.
If the capacity is too small, [some parts will be missing](https://arduinojson.org/v6/faq/why-is-the-output-incomplete/).

The solution is to increase the capacity of the [`JsonDocument`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/).
Use the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/) to know the memory requirements for your project.

Comment: It is not at all logical that the 'Time' Property would persist but not the value.  Nor is the requirement for the allocation to be N+2 whats actually in there.  But sure, downvote my question.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. If you believe ArduinoJson is broken, please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/new). If you want to learn how the library works, please read [the documentation](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/).